# Error in using pyspark with Jupyter

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I followed the instructions given on [this website](https://wegetsignal.wordpress.com/2016/03/24/setup-to-run-jupyter-notebook-with-pyspark/), but everytime I open a new pyspark notebook I'm still getting the following kernel error. How would I go about resolving this?

```
[E 15:39:28.693 NotebookApp] Failed to run command:
[u'/anaconda/bin/python', u'-m', u'ipykernel', u'-f', u'/run/user/1000/jupyter/kernel-f04c7a43-accb-403b-9632-d47e6728387e.json']
    PATH='/home/username/anaconda2/bin:/srv/spark/bin:/usr/local/scala/bin:/home/username/anaconda2/bin:/home/username/anaconda2/bin:/srv/spark/bin:/home/username/bin:/home/username/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin'
    with kwargs:
{'cwd': u'/home/username', 'stdin': -1, 'preexec_fn': <function <lambda> at 0x7f7280b3c320>, 'stderr': None, 'stdout': None}

 [E 15:39:28.712 NotebookApp] Unhandled error in API request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 457, in wrapper
    result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1015, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 237, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1021, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/handlers.py", line 62, in post
    kernel_id=kernel_id))
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1015, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 237, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1021, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session
    kernel_name)
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1015, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 237, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1021, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 92, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1015, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 237, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 285, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 87, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 243, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 189, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/launcher.py", line 123, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
```

Comment: You could read the Apache Toree documentation, which is the more up-to-date documentation on Spark notebooks

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure where you got that website from, but getting jupyter to work is much easier than this. All you need to do is set the environment variables `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'` and then run pyspark. There are actually directions for this embedded in the pyspark command located in spark/bin.

If you are running PySpark on a cluster and need to access your notebook from a networked computer make sure to add `ip` and `port` values to your `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS` string. Like so:

`export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8899'`

Then you can just open up a browser and type in `computer_name:8899` (where computer name is the name of the box from which you launched pyspark) and you will find your notebook.